# Why am I getting an 'AnimationViewRenderer doesn't exist in the context' error in Xamarin Forms for Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, lottie

Why doesn't AnimationViewRenderer exist in the context error when trying to add Lottie animation in Xamarin forms Android project's MainActivity.cs? I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 5):

Try to downgrade from 2.7.0 to 2.6.3

Answer (score 5):

After installing Lottie version 3.1.2 for Xamarin.Forms I had the same issue. The reason was that this specific version of Lottie has a dependency on Mono runtime version 10 but my Android project was Mono version 9. So once I upgraded MonoAndroid to 10, everything was working fine and I could use `AnimationViewRenderer.Init()`. However, I did not even need to initialize `AnimationViewRenderer` ; I just add the Lottie XAML component to my page and it is working perfectly.

You can check what version of Mono your Lottie requires by going to NuGet package manager, selecting the package and underneath `Dependencies` you should be able to see the required MonoAndroid version.

Answer (score 2):

With latest version of `Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie`, you do not need to call AnimationViewRenderer.Init(); anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add

```
AnimationViewRenderer.Init();
```

After initialising Forms in Android MainActivity.

A good post explaining the whole process:
https://xamgirl.com/lottie-animations-step-by-step-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I did that @Bruno but AnimationViewRenderer.Init(); is showing error. It says AnimationViewRenderer doesnot exist in this context.

Comment: You have all the packages installed, in both Forms and .Android project? Check your project if the Lottie package is actually installed.